# Creating makefile for multiple executions

Tags: c++, makefile

I have checked previous questions but did not find similar to mine:

I have client and server two processes

First I execute on ubuntu gcc:

`g++ -o a daemon.cpp exclude_fucntion.cpp -lpthread -std=c++11`
and then to run `./a`

Client execution:

`g++ -o b user_main.cpp client.cpp`
excute `./b`

Can  I create make file so that on execute it bot `a` and `b` can be created?
Or how makefile can be useful for my case?

I am fairly new to makefile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make will build the first target unless targets are specified. So actually make all will be run if make is executed with the following Makefile. This requests targets a and b to be up to date, which are specified below. (Remember to replace leading blanks with a tab)

```
all: a b

a: daemon.cpp exclude_fucntion.cpp
        g++ -o a daemon.cpp exclude_fucntion.cpp -lpthread -std=c++11

b: user_main.cpp client.cpp
        g++ -o b user_main.cpp client.cpp
```

Comment: thanks, so to use this I need to save as `makefile`? then how to execute it?

Comment: Usually as Makefile (first character in upper case). Just run "make" or "make a" or "make b". First will do both, while the others just build one target.

Comment: You can avoid repeating the filenames in the makefile using Make's automatic variables e.g. `g++ -o $@ $^`

Comment: Indeed, but I think, that step would have made the Makefile confusing for beginners. Advanced Makefiles can become arbitrarily complex.

Comment: cool!, upvote the question if you think it will useful to other! and congo for your first point gaining answer!